# Keep screen alive

Tags: linux, process, gnu-screen

I have a problem using screen. I know that the screen session works while the main process works, but how can I keep alive this session? I need this because there are some child processes are killed when session is shutting down.

How I start a session:

```
-A -m -d -S test  mytestapplication
```

Maybe I need to start the child processes outside of the screen session, but how? Maybe I need to set screen to keep the session alive until all processes inside have been shut down, but how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question. If you want to prevent `screen` from terminating automatically once all of its child processes have exited, you can set the `zombie` command in your configuration file (either system-wide or in your home directory), e.g.:

```
zombie KR
```

This will prevent windows with finished processes from closing automatically and keep the `screen` session alive indefinitely. The first character (`K`) following the `zombie` command invocation then kills the current window of a finished process, while the second character (`R`) attempts to restart the associated process. Given that you're running screen with the `-d` and `-m` flags, you'll obviously need to attach to the session with `screen -r` or `-R`.